# FreeBSD-11 EZJail install fails with tar unable to chdir

Tags: freebsd, jail

On a FreeBSD-11.1 host I removed an existing installation of ezjail using the following commands:

```
pkg remove ezjail
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/ezjail.conf
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/ezjail
chflags -R noschg /usr/jails
rm -rf /usr/jails
zfs destroy -r zroot/ezjail
```

I also checked for `/etc/fstab.*` and found none.

I then reinstalled *ezjail* using *pkg* and recreated the *zfs ezjail* partition:

```
zfs create -p zroot/ezjail
```

I also modified `/usr/local/etc/ezjail.conf` to use *zfs*:

```
ezjail_use_zfs="YES"
ezjail_use_zfs_for_jails="YES"
ezjail_jailzfs="zroot/ezjail"
```

However, when I run `ezjail-admin install` I get this error:

```
ezjail-admin install
base.txz                                      100% of   99 MB  621 kBps 02m45s
tar: could not chdir to '/usr/jails/fulljail'

ll /usr/jails
total 0

ll /usr/local/etc/ezjail
total 0

zfs list | grep jail
zroot/ezjail              176K   883G    88K  /zroot/ezjail
zroot/ezjail/fulljail      88K   883G    88K  /zroot/ezjail/fulljail
```

What has happened and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue arose because the initial install of *ezjail* on this system did not use *zfs*.  Consequently, the directories `/usr/jails/fulljail` and `/usr/jails/newjail` were created on the `zroot/usr` dataset.  When I witched *ezjail* over to *zfs* I did not realise that this had happened.  Somehow the existence of these two directories in `zpool/usr` conflicted with the same directories in `zroot/ezjail` under its mount point `/usr/jails`.

This condition was only discovered after I had destroyed `zroot/ezjail` in preparation for a clean install of *ezjail*.  My solution was to also remove these directories and the entire `/usr/jail` directory tree from `zroot/usr` before reinstalling *ezjail* with zfs enabled in `/usr/local/etc/ezjail.conf`.

To lessen the pain of all this I made an archive of the jail first and recreated it from the archive following the *ezjail* reinstallation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you miss the `mountpoint` for your pool, try something like:

```
# zfs create -o mountpoint=/usr/jails zpool/jails
```

Check this [quick setup](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/howto-quick-setup-of-jail-on-zfs-using-ezjail-with-pf-nat.30063/) guide as a reference.

Comment: @JamesB.Byrne what version of `ezjail` are you using? from changelog `V1.3.1`:  ezjail-admin now prevents a Jail called fulljail to be created and refines the error message in case the user wants to create basejail, newjail or flavours.

Comment: I am not sure what happened on that host but I can no longer replicate the issue.  The next day I was able to create jails using ezjail-admin on that host without any problem.